# Sending variable to another class sub: Cannot refer to an instance member

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, variables

I am kind of stumped about an issue I have been trying to figure out. Here is my issue that I am facing. I have two classes: CustomerFind.vb and CreateInvoice.vb. The user clicks on a search button to open another form that is top most, when the user searches for that customer the results are then displayed in a DataGridView. The user then selects that row for the customer and then clicks "Ok". I need to send that CustomersID from (CustomerFind.vb) to --> (CreateInvoice.vb). Once I have that variable in CreateInvoice I need to use that variable to pass into a function to get a table back of that customers details... See below for what I have already...

This opens the CustomerFind.vb form...

```
  Private Sub btnFindCustomer_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFindCustomer.Click
    Dim findCustomer As New CustomerFind
    findCustomer.ShowDialog()
  End Sub
```

Once the user picks their customer the variable is passed to the other class...

```
  Public Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim intCustomerID As Integer = dgvSearchResults.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value

    CreateInvoice.CreateNewInvoice(intCustomerID)

  End Sub
```

This is the sub from CreateInvoice.vb that I am passing the variable too...

```
 Public Shared Sub CreateNewInvoice(ByVal intCustomerID As Integer)

    'Datatable to hold returned results'
    Dim oTable As DataTable
    'Get the data that we need for the customer'
    oTable = CustomerHelper.GetCustomer(intCustomerID)

    txtFirstName.Text = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("First_Name") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("First_Name")))
    txtLastName.Text = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("Last_Name") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("Last_Name"))
    txtCity.Text = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("City") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("City"))
    cboState.SelectedValue = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("State") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("State"))
    txtAddress.Text = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("Address") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("Address"))
    txtZipCode.Text = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("Zip_Code") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("Zip_Code"))
    txtEmail.Text = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("Email") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("email"))
    txtHomePhone.Text = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("Home_Phone") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("Home_Phone"))
    txtCellPhone.Text = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("Cell_Phone") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("Cell_Phone"))
    txtMiddleInitial.Text = IIf(oTable.Rows(0).Item("Middle_Initial") Is DBNull.Value, "NA", oTable.Rows(0).Item("Middle_Initial"))

End Sub
```

THE ISSUE RELIES IN HERE. ALL OF THE TEXTFIELDS CANNOT REFER TO AN INSTANCE MEMBER OF A CLASS FROM WITHIN A SHARED METHOD... I need to fill these fields from the table that comes back.

I am not sure what I am missing here, maybe I am just tired...

Thanks!

Comment: Does `CreateNewInvoice` have to be Shared?

Comment: @chue x No it doesn't, I've tried that, but when I remove share I can't send the variable to that sub...

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what you expect, but I think you may need this (Pass CustomerId from CustomerFind.vb to CreateInvoice.vb). For this you can use the following:

Create an invisible label and assign CustomerId to the label in CustomerFind.vb like

```
  inlabel.Text=""+CustomerId
```

In the CreateInvoice.vb

```
   Dim id as Integer
   id=CustomerFind.inlabel.text
```

Now you can use the CustomerId

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done any forms development, but don't you want to do something like:

```
Public Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim intCustomerID As Integer = dgvSearchResults.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
    Dim invoiceDlg as New CreateInvoice

    ' new field in you invoice class
    invoiceDlg.CustomerID = intCustomerID
    ' set up text fields in your dialog init function instead of CreateNewInvoice()
    invoiceDlg.ShowDialog();
End Sub
```

Comment: This will not work...Sorry. I've tried this, the funny thing is I am passing the variable to the sub, it then is getting a table back and then I try to set the textbox fields from the table (NO ERRORS) but nothing appears in the textboxes?

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR - I guess I dont have a good enough understanding of your invoice class to suggest anything else.